# How do I login to a Postgres database without a password?

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

Right now my Postgres' pg_hba.conf file has the following lines:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
#Should allow connection without password
host    all all 0.0.0.0/0   trust
host    all all ::0/0   trust
```

(*I know that this is insecure. I'm just testing, and once it is successful, I'll keep it only specific users & databases*)

My understanding was that `trust` should allow a user to connect without a password.

But when I do `psql -U postgres -d postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -w`, I get the error message: `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

What do I need to do to allow users to connect without a password?

Comment: Did you reload the configuration after changing the file?

Comment: Yes, I did that. I'm sure that it is loaded, because I had made a mistake in the file earlier, and postgres refused to load till I corrected it.

Comment: Is there any line **before** those that you have shown us?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name; I've updated the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `pg_hba.conf` is checked for an authentication request, the **first** match determines the rule.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

> The first record with a matching connection type, client address, requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication. There is no “fall-through” or “backup”: if one record is chosen and the authentication fails, **subsequent records are not considered**

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

In your case the lines:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

are matched **before** the `trust` lines you have added, therefor Postgres requires a password. If you want to disable password authentication completely you have to disable the `md5` authentication, e.g. by commenting those lines.